# Navbar item moves to center when changing page

Tags: html, css, webflow

The menu button on my navbar is shifting to the center whenever Im visiting any page other than home.

Still new to using Webflow and I have no idea as to why the item is moving on (nav bar is set as a symbol)
[image]

And here its moved over

[image]

Comment: have you any sample code of two page ? we must see your code or inspect page for check this problem .

Comment: Either you don't use the same code for your navbar on both pages, or you might be overwriting / reusing a class which simply overwrites your normal navbar code. So check if you haven't overwritten any code. This can be easily done by using Element Inspect on your navbar and then see if any of the css components have a dash through them

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix it, I had to adjust the layout of the navbar whenever I wasn't on the current screen.